# How to get the value between two asterisk in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How to get the value between two asterisk in excel?

for example:

I have these: `TXI*GS*346.32*13*SP*ON*3***103634408RT0001`

I only want to get the value 346.32

i these data like this for A1:A20 how can i replace them all using VBA?

Comment: With a code, or manually? With or without VBA? Explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub extractFirstNumber()

    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    ' Match numbers of the form 123 or 123.45
    objRegEx.Pattern = "\d+(\.\d*)?"

    ' Iterate over the first 20 rows in first column
    For i = 1 To 20
        Set objMatch = objRegEx.Execute(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        If objMatch.Count = 1 Then
            ' If there is a match, replace the cell value
            Cells(i, 1).Value = objMatch(0)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit**

```
Sub extractFirstAndThirdNumber()

    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    ' Match numbers of the form 123 or 123.45 between asteriks
    objRegEx.Pattern = "\*(\d+(\.\d*)?)"
    objRegEx.Global = True

    ' Iterate over the first 20 rows in first column
    For i = 1 To 20
        Set objMatch = objRegEx.Execute(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        If objMatch.Count >= 2 Then
            ' If there is a match, replace the cell value
            'Cells(i, 1).Value = objMatch(0)
            Cells(i, 3).Value = objMatch(0).SubMatches(0)
            Cells(i, 4).Value = objMatch(2).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi amadeus.. thanks for your reply.. but where should i put this code?

Comment: i tried to run the script but it did not iterate.. it only changes the first cell which is A1

Comment: Go to the Visual Basic Editor (press ALT+F11 or via the developer tab) and click on the sheet where you want to replace the cells. Paste the code to the window and execute the macro (press F5)

Comment: Sorry, the code went over the first row, instead of the first column. Try the edited code.

Comment: it worked! however how can i put this to a button..

i'm going to put the button on Sheet 1 and the changes should be made on sheet 2

Comment: oh one last question...

what about if my value is this

Comment: IT1*00010*2640*EA*0.41**CB*000000000010006267*UP*628919006656

i need to get 00010 and 0.41

Comment: Do you want 00010 and 0.41 in the same cell? And what is the general pattern?

Comment: Thanks!

I'm afraid i still need help...

            Sheets("IT1").Select
            Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

Can you make this script to loop on Column B instead of column a?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub useSplit()
    Dim s As String
    s = "TXI*GS*346.32*13*SP*ON*3***103634408RT0001"
    Dim a() As String
    a = Split(s, "*")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        Debug.Print a(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what if i have these data on A1-A20?

Comment: @ArgeMotoharu loop through A1:A20 and repeat the procedure of splitting the contents into an array and process each cell one-by-one.